# Adding item in a List of map

Tags: dart

Can someone explain me why is this happening, please!

```
Map<String, Object> pedidoUnitario = {
  'Name': '',
};

List<Map<String, Object>> pedidoUser = [];

void main() {

  pedidoUnitario.update('Name', (var val) => 'Lincoln');
  pedidoUser.add(pedidoUnitario);

  print(pedidoUser);

  pedidoUnitario.update('Name', (var val) => 'Emilio');
  pedidoUser.add(pedidoUnitario);

  print(pedidoUser);
}
```

This is printing me

```
[{Name: Lincoln}]
[{Name: Emilio}, {Name: Emilio}]
```

I was hoping to see something like:

```
[{Name: Lincoln}, {Name: Emilio}]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *updated* the same object. Then added it to the list. So now you have *the same object* in the list *twice*.

What you want is to *create a new object* and add *that* to the list.

This:

```
Map<String, Object> pedidoUnitario = {
  'Name': '',
};

List<Map<String, Object>> pedidoUser = [];

void main() {
  final firstEntry = Map<String, Object>.from(pedidoUnitario)
    ..update('Name', (var val) => 'Lincoln');

  pedidoUser.add(firstEntry);

  print(pedidoUser);

  final secondEntry = Map<String, Object>.from(pedidoUnitario)
    ..update('Name', (var val) => 'Emilio');

  pedidoUser.add(secondEntry);

  print(pedidoUser);
}
```

will print

> [{Name: Lincoln}]

> [{Name: Lincoln}, {Name: Emilio}]